# access to zoom videos that was recorded by someone else

Tags: zoom-meeting

I'm teaching on a website of private tutors when the lesson is about to start I click on some button on the website and then a zoom link opens the zoom app. The website records the lesson and after the student can watch the video. But me (the teacher) can't, teachers don't have access to those videos.

Since zoom is third party app I was wondering if there's a way to access to those videos.

during a lesson my zoom looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUqxU.png)

I tried to go to zoom website and I signed in and I didn't found those recording

Comment: You may record a Zoom meeting, but only if you are the host. Are you?

Comment: It shows that I'm the host, but still I can't access the recording

Comment: Are you using the free Zoom version?

Comment: I didn't pay for a zoom account, but I guess that the website generate meeting URLs via paid account

Comment: Try to look in [Recording](https://go.zoom.us/account/setting?tab=recording), Cloud or Local Recording tab.

Comment: @harrymc If I generate my own meeting then it saves the recording on my local computer, but if I connect via the meeting URL that was generated by the website I can't see the recording

Comment: You should contact that website and ask how to access your own recordings.